# Which line called the function?

Tags: powershell

I have a function I use for debugging which is called in 100's of places. Sometimes I don't know where it was called from so then I have to send it "called for Line 890"... but then if I change my script its wrong.

So is there a way to get a function to print out which line it got called from?

Eg:

```
   1: function debug($obj){$obj | %{$_.PSObject.Properties...}
...
 890: debug $param
```

I need 'debug' to print out which line/function/block called it, in this case line 890.

Thanks :)

Comment: why not use the debugger instead?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819480.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the debugger, you can use the call stack to determine which function called the code:

```
function foo {
    'Caller {0}' -f (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command
}

function bar {
    foo
}

foo
bar
```

Output

```
Caller <ScriptBlock>
Caller bar
```